# customizing spring 3 mvc:annotation for RequestMappingHandlerMapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

I am using `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` and I would like to configure `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` for disabling `useTrailingSlashMatch`. When I declare another RequestMappingHandlerMapping, I will end up 2 `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`. How can I configure `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you have already noted, this is feasible in xml by removing `mvc:annotation-driven` and replacing with the entire xml equivalent:

```
<bean name="handlerAdapter" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="webBindingInitializer">
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.bind.support.ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer">
            <property name="conversionService" ref="conversionService"></property>
            <property name="validator">
                <bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.XmlAwareFormHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean name="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
    <property name="useTrailingSlashMatch" value="true"></property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with Java config to override `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` value

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "base.package.name")
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping rmh = super.requestMappingHandlerMapping();
        rmh.setUseTrailingSlashMatch(false);
        return rmh;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already solved by replacing entire xml configuration by programmatic java one. But I had also tried this one which did not helped me.

Comment: Okay, Java config worked for you; Good. If you get time, please updated the post by adding details of your resolution. It will provide heads up for upcoming viewers :)

Comment: Actually, I have same intention. But my solution is not answer of the question. The real solution must be based on xml configuration.

Comment: @Cemo Can you explain why this solution didnt work? It seems to be very similar to this [solution](http://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-mvc/spring-requestmappinghandlermapping-interceptor-annotation-example)

Comment: @AlanBerezin The time when I was asked this question, I was using completely xml based approach for configuring beans. Mixing configurations seems a little bid dangerous for me. Since It can easily trap my colleagues into a pitfall. Nowadays I am avid supporter of Spring Boot and java config. I have completely left xml configurations which are ugly and less type safe when you compared with java config. This answer probably would work now as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a solution that doesn't involve duplicating functionality in Spring then you can override the DisplatcherServlet.  in Servlet 3.0 container this might look like:

```java
@WebServlet(name="spring-dispatcher", loadOnStartup=1, urlPatterns={"/"},
        initParams={
            @WebInitParam(name="contextConfigLocation", 
            value="/WEB-INF/spring/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml")})
public class MyDispatcherServlet extends DispatcherServlet {

    @Override
    protected void initStrategies(ApplicationContext context) {
        super.initStrategies(context);
        for (RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping handlerMapping 
                : BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(
                    context, RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.class, true, false).values()) {

            handlerMapping.setUseTrailingSlashMatch(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wrote a blog post about this http://www.scarba05.co.uk/blog/2013/03/configure-the-default-handlermapping-supplied-by-mvcannotation-driven-in-spring-3-2/

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your spring configuration file to toggle the `useTrailingSlashMatch` field.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
    <property name="useTrailingSlashMatch" value="true">
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I have already tried this. `mvc:annotation-driven` is creating another RequestMappingHandlerMapping. I have stated on my question it.