# How to modify PathMatch in Spring 3.2.x?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

This is a follow up to a [prior SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21002745/827480).

Spring 3.2 has deprecated `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` in lieu of `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`.  Prior to Spring 3.2, I was able to use `AnnotationMethodHandlerConfigurer` to configure the PathMatcher, but I cannot seem to find the equivalent in Spring 3.2.

There is a `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` class to customize the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`, however I do not see how I can specify a custom `PathMatcher`.  To be frank, I cannot find where a PathMatcher is used in Spring 3.2.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

As an FYI for someone who comes across this in the future, I also found this [reference link](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10163) that has some information as to how to do it via XML, however I have not tested it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `setPathMatcher` is defined in the abstract base class `AbstractHandlerMapping`. So you can configure the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` to use another `PathMatcher`.

Comment: Funny; it seems as though Spring has gone backwards for XML configuration.  Before 3.2, you could have used the `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapterConfigurer` in addition to `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` tag, but that seems to no longer be the case with the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` since the annotation instantiates its own `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` bean.  So my choices are a post-processing bean, remove the annotation and configure by hand (uggh!) or move everything to JavaConfig.  Or is there a util class equiv to `AnnotationMethodHandlerConfigurer` available to me?

Comment: @EricB. I'm not quite sure I understand you, but you should always be able to configure `<bean name="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">...`

Comment: From what I've read, <mvc:annotation-driven> already instantiates its own RequestMappingHandlerMapping bean.  So when creating my own handlerMapping bean, there does not seem to be a way to indicate to Spring to use my custom bean during the <mvc:annotation-driven> setup.  Hence my previous comment.  But I have not tested anything out yet; this is all from things I have gathered reading up on it. (Ex: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13581472/827480)

Comment: @EricB. I see. I'm not aware of any methods other than the ones you've listed.

Comment: You don't have to move everything to javaconfig, only the `@EnableWebMvc` instead of `<mvc:annotation-driven />` would be enough. Everything else can still be in XML.

Comment: @M.Deinum You can't configure `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` using `@EnableWebMvc`. You need to extend `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` directly.

Comment: Correct most people do both create a `@Configuration` class with also the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation and have this class extend `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` and then override the `requestMappingHandlerMapping` (with calling super) and then simply do the additional configuration.

Comment: I realize all that.  Just find it a little backwards from Spring to have removed the ability to do it directly via XML and require JavaConfig.